# Website malware

Tags: web, malware, malware-detection

few days ago I've noticed that my site has a malware warining on Google. So now I have found what caused the problem, and removed the bad scripts, but the malware warning is still showing. Can anyone tell me what should I do next to remove the warning from google chrome.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an internet service and not development

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't the right forum for that kind of question. You could try https://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please review this link
http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=163634&ctx=cb&src=cb&cbid=elq3fvt39ebd&cbrank=0

When you have cleaned out the site you can request the reconsideration there. You will have to signup for Google webmaster tools (which is free) and add your site. This helps verify to google that you are a legitimate webmaster and not a robot.

Answer (score 0):

It takes time for Google to revisit your website and check if it's clean. You can see things up by submitting a reconsideration request, but even with that you should allow 3-4 weeks minimum.